# How can we log file download successes and failures from IIS7?

Tags: logging, iis-7, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a dedicated server:

- IIS7
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

This servers sole use is to serve files ~120MB in size.

We're looking for the simplest way to log how many downloads were:

- Started
- Completed
- Not completed

For each of the files we host.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: How are people requesting/receiving the files? Are they just HTTP requests for the files directly?

Comment: @techie007 yes just normal HTTP requests.